# How do I know if it's safe to travel to a country at a specific time?

Tags: safety, international-travel, online-resources

Are there travel websites constantly updated with safety tips and political situation of countries?

Comment: This question may be regarded as too broad to be on-topic for this site. But if you ask specific questions about the countries and times you want to travel to they will definitely be on-topic.

Answer (score 26):

Many countries have travel advice agencies run by their respective governments.

- The US: http://travel.state.gov/travel/travel_1744.html
- The UK: http://www.fco.gov.uk/en/travel-and-living-abroad/travel-advice-by-country/
- Australia: http://www.smartraveller.gov.au/zw-cgi/view/Advice/
- France (in french): http://www.diplomatie.gouv.fr/fr/conseils-aux-voyageurs_909/index.html
- Germany (in German): http://www.auswaertiges-amt.de/DE/Laenderinformationen/SicherheitshinweiseA-Z-Laenderauswahlseite_node.html

and so on. It's best to check the website for your particular country, as there can exist threats to your nationality that don't exist towards others (for example, anti-american sentiment, etc).

Comment: But don't forget that advices from US government for US citizen about North Korea may not be relevant for Chinese citizen.

Comment: good idea mouviciel, feel free to add links to other countries' travel advice boards.

Answer (score 4):

Generally the foreign affairs departement of your government will contain travel advice for countries, it's worth checking there.
Not only that if you are going to somewhere dangerous, a lot of governments operate a service where you can register with the local embassy in event of emergency etc.

Answer (score 3):

You can also check the your embassy web-site of a specific country, although that might depend on where you're from. Works for me at least (Dutch).

Comment: Depends on the country you plan to go to. Some are notoriously slow at updating any kind of relevant travel advice, and can often be biased.

Answer (score 3):

And regarding other kind of safety, weather and such, I was always prefer do check the reports on the country's local weather agency, it usually is more detailed and more oriented to each countries specific details (mountain, etc..).

Answer (score 2):

The country/states government site mostly remains updated with the safety tips\road conditions. The political situations is not necessarily updated though.